# How to have one setup with Stripe on a peer-to-peer marketplace?

Tags: stripe-payments

I've built a peer to peer ecommerce website and while it works, I'm getting some feedback from users (which at this point are just a few of my friends) that the Stripe interactions are a little confusing.

I think this is more to do with how I've set up my site than Stripe itself.

Here is the current setup:

All users must add their debit/credit card when completing their profile. I'm using a simple card input, the one that comes from `<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>`.

Any users who want to sell their items must also create a Stripe Connect account (I'm using Connect Express). This is the one where they are taken to Stripe.com and redirected to my site upon adding their bank account info. This onboarding process is only initiated when a user tries to upload an item to sell.

To complete a transaction, I'm using:

```
charge = stripe.Charge.create(
    amount=amount_to_owner+200,
    currency="usd",
    customer = stripe_customer_id,
    application_fee_amount=200,
    transfer_data={
        "destination": owner_connect_acct,
        }
)
```

So, I'm charging the user with the customer id, and paying the other user to their connect account.

The fact that there are two separate actions - one where the user simply adds their card info, and the other where they go through Connect, might be confusing to some people.

Is there a way I can do this all in one? I'm open to anything and don't mind changing up things. Thank you in advance for any guidance.

Comment: I think this is really a UX problem more than a code one. Have a clear distinction between "buying" and "selling" mode.

Comment: Stripe Support can probably help as they give this kind of advice every day -- https://support.stripe.com/email